# How to add extra text to a TextBoxFor in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm making a MVC form with all kind of fields. These are all in the normal MVC form

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Auto.Length, New With {.Class = "form-control", .Disabled = True})
```

Here I want to add the unit of measure in this field directly, in this case 'mm'.
I've already created an Extension which I'd like to call directly, but without success.

```
<Extension>
Public Function Add_Appendix(value As Integer, appendix As String) As String

    Return value.ToString & " " & appendix
End Function
```

Would be nice if I could call it like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Auto.Length.Add_Appendix("mm"), New With {.Class = "form-control", .Disabled = True})
```

But then I'm getting the error

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

How can I make this possible?
thx.

Comment: You do not use the `*For` helpers for random expressions. For random expressions you use the ones without `For`, `TextBox` in your case.

Comment: @GSerg: thah, that simple.. I've wasted too much time to find this simple solution. Thx mate! If you put this explanation as an aswer I'll check it as correct.

Comment: OT - "Appendix" is the wrong terminology there.  It should be "Suffix".

Comment: You do not need your `Add_Appendix` method. Assuming the property is a numeric type, then use a `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0} mm", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]` and use `EditorFor()` (but then you will need to strip the suffix again before submitting so suggest you just add a `<span>` after the textbox to render `mm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*For` helpers do not allow random expressions because they need to bind to an existing property of your model.
If you want to use a `*For` helper, you need to create a property on your model that represents the amended value.

If you don't want to do that, you have to use the helpers without `*For` (or not use any helpers at all), e.g. `@Html.TextBox` in your case.

Arguably though you should not be doing this because it only makes your life harder. You will have to make sure you strip the added `mm` when you post your model, and to make sure it does not add `mm` a second time. Instead put `mm` after the textbox.